Ctrl + . shortcut not working in Google IDX for Flutter project
I'm working on a Flutter project using Google's IDX, which runs in Google Chrome. While most shortcuts are functioning as expected, the Ctrl + . (used for quick fixes and suggestions) doesn't seem to work. The same shortcut works fine in VS Code desktop. Every time I have to manually use the mouse and click the yellow bulb to access suggestions, which slows down my workflow. Has anyone encountered this issue or know of any potential fixes?

As IDX is very new and still in Beta so you would be better off reviewing https://developers.google.com/idx/support/help
